# How to prevent breaking of a string into a character list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.x

I have a list that could contain 1 or many elements. The code below works fine if it has multiple elements in the list. However, if there is only one element, it breaks it into character list.

```
my_dict = {fruit: ['apple', 'banana', 'carrot']}

li = my_dict.get('fruit')

for fruit in li:
    print fruit
```

Comment: Change the code upstream to always return a list, even if it's only 1 string.

Comment: Could you modify your example to show how you're storing only one element?  I suspect you're doing `{'fruit': 'apple'}` when you should be doing `{'fruit': ['apple']}`

Answer (score 1):

Even when there is only one element, it will be treated as a single item in a list as long as you enclose it in square brackets. So this:

```
my_dict = {'fruit': ['apple']}
```

will work as you expect, while this:

```
my_dict = {'fruit': 'apple'}
```

will not.

(Also, the names of your dictionary keys (e.g. `fruit`) should be quoted, since they're not variables.)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a list with a single element

```
my_dict = {'fruit': ['apple']}

li = my_dict.get('fruit')

for fruit in li:
    print(fruit)
```

And you get

```
apple
```

If you change your dictionary to

```
my_dict = {'fruit': 'apple'}
```

you will get each character of that string when you loop over that object.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure *consistent data types*. You assume a list of elements with the for-loop. When you pass a string, Python splits it into characters.

You should use something like

```
my_dict = {'fruit': ['apple']}
```

when working with one element only.

If you can't ensure a list as the dictionary value you have to check the type manually.

```
my_dict = {'fruit': 'apple'}

li = my_dict.get('fruit')

if type(li) is list:
    for fruit in li:
        print(fruit)
else:
    print(li)
```